# Getting substring from response NSString

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring

I need to get substring `CODE`'s value (`X2.31`) from string

```
NSString *str = @"SHMU=\"\" CODE=\"X2.31\" XTN=\";
```

How could I get that particular substring?

Comment: You can either use `NSScanner` or `NSRegularExpression`

Comment: is it always in this format and number is preceeded by X ?

Answer (score 1):

Try the below one

```
  NSString *str = @"SHMU=\"\" CODE=\"X2.31\" XTN=\"";

 NSRange range = [str rangeOfString:@"CODE="];
 NSString *substring = [[str substringFromIndex:NSMaxRange(range)] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
 NSArray *str1 = [substring componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
 NSLog(@"the sub %@",[[str1 objectAtIndex:0] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]]);
```

And by string was "X2.31"

Comment: Thanks .....          I need to get substring CODE's value (X2.31) from string  CODE= is come in this String 

NSString *str = @"SHMU=\"\" CODE=\"X2.31\" XTN=\ LHNU=\"\" CODE=\"Z2.32\" XTN=\ GHMU=\"\" CODE=\"L2.3\" XTN=\";

How could I get that particular substring?

Comment: can you give me wat string your obtaining once more please edit it in your question for clarity or mark as comment

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *strOrg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"SHMU=\"\" CODE=\"X2.31\" XTN=\""] ;

NSString *strLeft = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"SHMU=\"\" CODE=\""] ;
NSString *strRight = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"\" XTN=\""] ;

NSLog(@"%@", [self getDataBetweenString:strOrg LeftString:strLeft RightString:strRight LeftOffset:13]);

- (NSString *)getDataBetweenString:(NSString *)orgString LeftString:(NSString *)leftString RightString:(NSString *)rightString LeftOffset:(NSInteger)leftPos;
{
    NSInteger left, right;
    NSString *foundData;
    NSScanner *scanner=[NSScanner scannerWithString:orgString];
    [scanner scanUpToString:leftString intoString: nil];
    left = [scanner scanLocation];
    [scanner setScanLocation:left + leftPos];
    [scanner scanUpToString:rightString intoString: nil];
    right = [scanner scanLocation] + 1;
    left += leftPos;
    foundData = [orgString substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(left, (right - left) - 1)];         return foundData;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is only **specific** to the **str** you posted.
Your number must be followed by First X.

```
float f=[[str componentsSeparatedByString:@"X"][1] floatValue];
```